# UI Router $state.go is not redirecting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is a common issue, I see it a ton but nothing seems to work. Here is what I'm doing. I want to have some dynamic animations with my states, so basically login will do some cool animations and move into the actual interface. Now, I started nesting the views like this:

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            title: "Login",
            views: {
                "master": {
                    controller: "LoginController",
                    templateUrl: "/components/login/login.html",
                    authentication: false
                }
            }
        })
        .state("logout", {
            url: "/logout",
            title: "Logout",
            authentication: false
        })
        .state('foo', {
            url: '/',
            controller: "HomeController",
            views: {
                "master": {
                    templateUrl: '/components/ui-views/masterView.html'
                },
                "sidebar@foo": {
                    templateUrl: '/components/sidebar/_sidebar.html'
                },
                "header@foo": {
                    templateUrl: '/components/header/_header.html'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('foo.inventory', {
            url: '/inventory',
            title: "Inventory",
            views: {
                "content@foo": {
                    controller: "InventoryController",
                    templateUrl: "/components/inventory/inventory.html"
                }
            }
        });
```

So while running this I need to redirect to logout, but it gets stuck. It won't move from this logout state at all.
Here is how I'm handling that:

```
function run($http, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $state, $templateCache, $timeout, AuthService, modalService, const) {
        var timeout;

        FastClick.attach(document.body);
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};

if ($state.current.name !== 'login' && !$rootScope.globals.guid) {
            $state.go('login');
        } else if ($state.current.name == 'login' && $rootScope.globals.guid) {
            $state.go('foo');
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, current, fromState, fromParams) {
            var authorizedRoles = next.level != undefined ? next.level : 1,
                needAuth = next.authentication != undefined ? next.authentication : true;

            if (needAuth) {
                if (!AuthService.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles, true)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast(const.auth.notAuthorized);
                        $state.go('foo', {});
                    } else {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast(const.auth.notAuthenticated);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (next.name == 'logout') AuthService.logout($rootScope.globals);
        });

}
```

So why would this not work? It seems like this work fine. But the `$state.go('login')` returns a bad value.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, or tell me what is wrong exactly.

Comment: just try window.location.hash="#login"; instead of $state.go('login') ..

Comment: That just hashes login at the end of the URL, doesn't do what I need it to do.

Comment: There is lot of parts missing, e.g. the $rootScope.globals.guid, or the **if** before $rootScope.$on is called where?... the best would be to reproduce the issue with some plunker, or share all the stuff.

Comment: It is getting in the `$state.go('login');` but the actual call returns: `value: Error: transition superseded` for some reason. No idea why. Even with $location.path('/login'); it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeHuebner where is  $state.go exactly ? what is the wrapper function of your whole code?

Comment: @levi `$state.go` is a function of ui-router for AngularJS.. It isn't doing what is it suppose to do, such as redirect the page. [UI Router $state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateproviderstatestatename-stateconfig)

Comment: @MikeHuebner I know hat $state.go is , I mean where is the complete context of your function.

Comment: @levi My bad! You had me confused! I posted a more partial version of the run function! Also, the $stateProvider is wrapped in Config. That is all that is in the config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the $state.go is in the run, there doesn't seem to be many docs on this topic. $state.go is not initialized yet and will not run.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. After debugging into how the attribute `ui-sref` works for hyperlinks, i found out that the `$state.go` is wrapped around $timeout in the core angular-ui library.

```
var transition = $timeout(function() {
                debugger;
                $state.go("app.authentication");
            });
```

Perhaps you could try the same. (Although the ui-sref event handler in the core library clearly mentions that this is a hack.)

Comment: saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

只需要升级ui-router版本就可以了，见连接地址：https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bluebird-promises/issues/11

If you upgrade to ui-router 0.3.2 it's actually been fixed there: angular-ui/ui-router@66ab048

Comment: Note that the official language in SO is English since it is difficult to monitor multi language posts. Please make sure that you translated your respond to English.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issues in my app, you are trying to call `$state.go` on an internal `ui-view` that is not relative to the state ,thats you are facing this problem, so try this :

```
app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 
function ($state, $rootScope, $timeout) {

 $timeout(function() { 
      $state.go('login');
    });   
}]);
```